# Flash audio recorder... with realtime mp3-encoding

Tags: flash, encoding, mp3, real-time

I have been looking for a flash audio recorder to embed on my web. But all the recorders that I have found do the encoding to mp3 at the end of the record. That takes too much time (for example for a 10 minutes recording, take about 5 minutes for encoding to mp3).

I have read that maybe that's not possible (see jordan comment on 27 September here: http://www.jordansthings.com/blog/?p=5 ).

Does someone know about any flash audio recorder able to do that, or at least if it would be technically possible?

I could try to modify the code, but after reading jordan's comment I don't feel very sure about if it is possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I tried Flabell's recorder, and beside the fact that it mysteriously hit its own stop button for me (perhaps some static in the room I was in??), the time to encode a long recording is entirely prohibitive (I record two hour interviews and had changed the xml settings file to allow up to 200 minutes, which is 12000 seconds).

The best solution I have found is to start a Google+ account and associated YouTube channel and record a Hangout-On-Air. One could also simply record directly into YouTube using their webcam capture tool.

A two hour recording (only available to a verified account, meaning you've replied to an email they send you) is transcoded almost immediately and can then be downloaded as an MP4 file from the Video Manager. I then can extract the audio using AOA audio extractor. The only problem with that solution is that you need to be online... so, I'm still looking for a different solution. http://www.aoamedia.com/audioextractor.htm

I HAD installed crouton linux onto the Chromebook I'm trying to get all this happening on (and Acer Intel 710) and ran Audacity, but the fact that the developer mode is so physically insecure (in that all someone has to do is hit the spacebar after they open the lid and all your linux installs and saved materials are wiped out) made me run back to trying to discover a solution that works on a Chromebook stock.

I also tried Soundation, but it limits how long you can record in a single track, so it is worthless to me. This is with a "Power User" account, yet! I'll be unsubscribing from that service... but it was another online-only solution anyway, and I'd like to see an offline solution appear.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue with one of my project. I found this one after doing a lot of searches

1. http://www.flabell.com/flash/Audio-Recorder-for-Adobe-Flash-350 (paid)
2. https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/ (free)

Comment: Hi Bimal, thanks for the answers... but flabell do the encoding at the end as well. The other solution (streaming the wav to the server) I had already seen, but is a different approach, and the user still need to wait that the server make the encoding...

I am using this player: https://github.com/clehner/sound-recorder-uploader

I will study again the code and give a try but I found it complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Flash Player based,  **streaming audio recorder** that uses the media server to handle the recording. Flabell's recorder captures raw audio and stores it in the RAM memory. When you press [STOP] that audio data is converted to mp3 using a wav2mp3 Flash/AS3 library.

[FLVAR](http://flvar.com) on the other hand uses Flash Player's native audio encoding capabilities (FP can encode audio using NellyMoser's ASAO and Speex) but the main difference is that while it's recording, it's sending the audio data to a media server like [Red5](https://code.google.com/p/red5/) (free and open source), [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) or [Adobe Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/ro/products/adobe-media-server-family.html). This means means that:

1. It can do long recordings
2. If the client crashes, no data is lost

The media server stores the audio in .flv files and you can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert them to mp3 (you might need to compile ffmpeg with Speex support if you're using Speex).

FLVAR is good for long recordings where not loosing data is important while Flabell's solution and Audior.ec are good for quick short recordings.